# Composition of Relations`

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, function-and-relation-composition

Note: this isn't a HW question. I'm doing problems from the book "Invitation  to Discrete Mathematics- Jirí Matousek, Jaroslav Nesetril"

The following is the question:

[image]

I tried by contradiction but couldn't make any progress.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What definition do you use for relation?

Comment: I didn't get your question @Joe

Comment: I was going to see if you said, “A subset of $X \times X$”, then ask you how many subsets there are, but @Berci gave you the answer.

Comment: @Joe thought you needed some clarification

Comment: Note: This *is* still a homework question, even if you set it for yourself.  As such, it is still preferred that you *show* what you have tried so we might see where you are actually having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Since $X$ is finite, so is the set of its possible relations, $P(X\times X)$ (with cardinality $2^{|X|^2}=:N$), so any sequence of at least $N+1$ relations over $X$ must contain a repetition. 
So does in particular the infinite sequence $R, R^2, R^3, \dots$.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate: "so any sequence of at least +1 relations over  must contain a repetition."

Comment: Elaboration: Pidge-on-hole principle

Comment: it's actually typed pigeonhole principle @Berci

Comment: @Berci what do you mean by any sequence of N+1 relations?